# Touch command not working in Terminal of VSC

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm new and still trying to figure out how to configure my development environment. I'm getting an error when using the touch command in Visual Studio Code. I can use `mkdir` to create a directory, but can't create a `.php` file. Here's the error I'm getting. Any ideas? Thank you!

> touch : The term 'touch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
>   is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + touch new.php
>   + ~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (touch:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Before asking a question, you should learn what environment you are in. 1) Visual Studio Code is not Visual Studio. 2) You are not in a Linux/macOS terminal, but a terminal panel in VSCode, which runs PowerShell in fact. So `touch` is obviously not a command there.

Answer (score 15):

To create a new empty file in PowerShell, you can use:

```
ni new.php
```

or, without aliases and defaults:

```
New-Item -Path X:\path -Name new.php -ItemType File
```

For details see `Get-Help New-Item` or view [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Amazing!  Had never heard of ni before. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

As [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) said

> You are not in a Linux/macOS terminal, but a terminal panel in VSCode, which runs PowerShell in fact. So touch is obviously not a command there.

Here's the command you can use for VSC to create a new file

```
code -r newFile.js
```

To open an existing file use the command

```
code -r fileName.js
```

Comment: This throws me the following error in VSCode: *The term 'code' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.*

Comment: @jeppoo1 That's because you don't have VSCode added to your PATH. PATH is where your computer will look for first when you input commands like "code". You need to let the computer know that typing "code" in terminal means open VSCode.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the touch command, use bash as your terminal. It will work then

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `git` then you can use directly git commands inside `VS Code`

Go inside VS `terminal`  you can open a terminal by clicking terminal on top of the `vs code`  Terminal tab.

Click on the down arrow and select `Git Bash`

That's it ;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on a Windows system using the PowerShell as the default terminal for VSCode, know that there is no such command (cmdlet) called `touch`.

However, there is a workaround to create new files from PowerShell using the following command:

```
echo $null >> filename
```

**Note:** As this is a workaround, I suggest you use it with caution.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the OS you are running on it might need a different configuration, for Linux (mint) I had to use the `ni` command to accomplish this

Try something like `ni fileName.anything`

Answer (score 1):

`cat > filename`

works for me in windows

Answer (score 1):

For Creating file from command prompt  like in linux
[image: New-Item tsconfig.json]

```
New-Item tsconfig.json
```

*New-item* is powershell command. Here creating tsconfig.json file simply use new-item command

### Creating Alias

*touch* is linux command you can create alias for touch like this.

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
set-alias touch new-item
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use git then, go to the folder of your project where you want to create a file, then right click and chose "git bash here". a terminal/command prompt type window will appear now you can type command "touch .newfilename".

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to use the touch command in Visual Studio it will not be recognized as a valid command in Windows PowerShell. The touch command is a Unix, Linux command used to create an empty file, and it may not be available in your current environment.
Alternatively, you can also use the following command in Windows PowerShell to create a new .php file:

New-Item -ItemType File new.php

This command creates a new file named "new.php" in the current directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should switch to the bash terminal and use touch command to create multiple files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).